# Remove Page Title from Static Frontpage

Tags: functions, filters, hooks, pages

I'd like to remove the post title from my static frontpage. Just that page.
I've created a child theme from a free Press75 theme. So I'd like to make this change in my child theme's function.php.

I used this code but it removes the title from all pages, posts and my navigation:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'remove_page_title' );

function remove_page_title() {
    if(is_page('138')) {
    }
    return '';
}
```

I thought it would just remove the title from the page with ID 138.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Create a [`front-page.php` template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Front_Page_display) and remove the title?

Comment: Stumbled upon this as I am having the exact same problem. Tried the Kaiser-Chip approach which worked fine - except it also removed all menu items + all post titles in the sidebar widget. Also, although it removed the title of the page, the styling of the title remained - including some padding and a border-bottom. 

Is there another solution?

Comment: This was the easiest solution. But it just seems like overkill to create a template just to remove the title. I'm able to do this in the functions.php when I use the Hybrid Framework, just by using one of Justin's hooks.

Comment: @Anders Could you delete this answer and add it as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

wrap your add_filter function call around a conditional tag and use the builtin return false function:

```
if ( is_page('138') )
{
      add_filter( 'the_title', '__return_false' );
}
```

Comment: I like this suggestion, but wouldn't *if ( ! is_front_page() )* be better to use than a hard-coded page ID, such as *if ( is_page( '138' ) )*?

Comment: @Chip Bennett - Surely better. But from reading the Q, the A fits well. IMO i think it's better to offer a solution that's as close as possible to the Q, even when there are lots of better solutions available. There's a saying where i come from: "The farmer doesn't eat what he doesn't know".

Comment: But this was the original issue: " I'd like to remove the post title from my static frontpage. Just that page." In which case, I would definitely recommend the front-page.php template file solution. In any case, your answer got my vote.

Comment: I add this code using page ID or is_front_page and nothing happens...

Comment: I'm not sure about the __return_false function. It could be named close to that. You could also write a small fn yourself that returns false and add it. Anyway, Chip's comment is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it!

Here's your original code:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'remove_page_title' );

function remove_page_title() {
   if(is_page('138')) {
   }
   return '';
}
```

What it's doing is adding a filter on `the_title` that doesn't accept any parameters.  That's your first mistake.  The `the_title` filter actually takes two parameters - the page/post title and the page/post id.  So first, let's rewrite our hook:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'remove_page_title', 10, 2 );
function remove_page_title( $title, $id ) {

}
```

This assigns our filter with a priority of 10 and lets us accept both parameters sent in by the filter.  Then we specify the parameters our function accepts.

Inside the function, we want to check if we're on the right page.  If we are, return `''`, if we aren't return the title:

```
if( '138' == $id ) return '';

return $title;
```

Your original function was *always* returning `''` when the filter ran.  That's why you were getting a blank title on every page, not just the page you wanted.

### Our full code

So your full filter, rewritten to accept parameters and use the proper logic:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'remove_page_title', 10, 2 );

function remove_page_title( $title, $id ) {
    if( '138' == $id ) return '';

    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is way how to remove main title heading (not  tag) from front page in 2020 while not removing the_title from menu items too:

```
function no_title_front_page( $title, $id = null ) {
    if (is_front_page() && !is_null( $id )) {
        return '';
    }
    return $title;

}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'no_title_front_page', 10, 2 );


function wpse309151_remove_title_filter_nav_menu( $nav_menu, $args ) {
    // we are working with menu, so remove the title filter
    remove_filter( 'the_title', 'no_title_front_page', 10, 2 );
    return $nav_menu;

}

// this filter fires just before the nav menu item creation process
add_filter( 'pre_wp_nav_menu', 'wpse309151_remove_title_filter_nav_menu', 10, 2 );

function wpse309151_add_title_filter_non_menu( $items, $args ) {
    // we are done working with menu, so add the title filter back
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'no_title_front_page', 10, 2 );
    return $items;

}

// this filter fires after nav menu item creation is done
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpse309151_add_title_filter_non_menu', 10, 2 );
```

Code based on [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/309356) answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way for header.php:

```
<?php if (is_page('138')) { echo'
<style type="text/css" title="text/css">
yourpagetitleselector {display:none;}
</style>'
; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly -- that you want to display no `<title>` for the front page -- you can use:

```
<title><?php if ( ! is_front_page() ) { the_title(); } ?></title>
```

Comment: `<title> !== the_title();` See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title Further more this exactly what @Chip Bennett suggested as a comment to my Answer.

Comment: Sheesh. I answered before Chip posted his comment. I also clarified my answer by "if I understand you correctly," which clearly I did not.

Comment: @Ryan: Sorry if i did you wrong. I just compared the time and there were 2min difference.

Comment: I do hope that answers, voting, reputation, etc. aren't terribly contentious here? I'm not really worried about them; what really matters is that people get help with solving their problems, yeah?

Comment: @kaiser: I appreciate that -- I was more upset at myself for not reading the question, which you correctly answered. It was a bit of a shock being a n00b on this site and getting downvoted but, as Chip says, it's about getting people their answers. :)

Comment: I'm very confused about how this site works. Ryan's answer doesn't look like Chips answer at all to me. It looks like Ryan is suggesting I put this in the template file and not the functions.php. I could be wrong, but I wanted to make this change using a hook or a filter. I'm completely confused as to why this is so difficult, since I've done it before using the Hybrid Theme Framework. Is it because my current theme does not have a hook in place for it? And The best solution so far is a comment to my original post and not one of the answers so how do I award credit?

Comment: @Intrepid Realist, when I gave this answer, I had not read your question closely. My solution is to adjust your header.php template, not functions.php as you asked. Because I misunderstood your question, I would comment on the answer that is closest to what you need. If you place the @ symbol before the person's name, it will notify them of the comment so they can get back to you (i.e., @kaiser, I don't really understand...).