# Removing title from page

Tags: functions, filters

Hello attempting to remove the title from static front page using the following  code is (not working) in my functions.php

```
    function remove_page_title() { if (is_front_page() )
{
      add_filter( 'the_title', '__return_false' );
}}
```

IS there something missing? Thanks in advance

PS I know I can hard code it in to my page template with

```
<?php if(!is_front_page()) { ?><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2><?php } ?>
```

but I'd rather not change the template

Comment: see this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/368823/50021

Answer (score 1):

How about hiding the title with CSS?

```
.entry-title {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: a good fallback solution thank you but am really after a php solution to learn. Thanks again though

Comment: not good for SEO