# How to remove title (home) from static page skeleton template

Tags: pages, title, customization

I am trying to remove the page title (home) from my index page. I made my home page my static page.

I am using the skeleton theme https://github.com/simplethemes/skeleton_wp

I'm new to wordpress so I hope I'm explaining this right.

Comment: how to remove page title from front page: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/368823/50021

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used the theme, but the code seems to show that there is an option to hide the title. Line 23 of https://github.com/simplethemes/skeleton_wp/blob/master/skeleton/loop-page.php shows post meta for `hidetitle`. Look for a checkbox on the edit page maybe?

Comment: Ok, I removed the title from the static page buy selecting a different page template in the edit page area. Not the hard solution I was looking for,lol but problem solved.