# Apply the_title() filter in post & page title, but not in menu title

Tags: posts, menus, filters, pages, title

I use the following code to change the title of WordPress **posts** and **pages**. But it changes nav menu item titles too, which I want to avoid.

I want to change the title of posts and pages in: **home page**, all **archive pages** and all **widgets** (recent posts widget, random post widget, etc.)

There are similar questions in both Stack Overflow and WP Stack Exchange suggesting to use `in_the_loop()` function. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me, because if I place it, it also affects the sidebar widgets.

That means, if I use `in_the_loop()` function,  `the_title` filter does not affect `recent posts widget`, `random post widget` etc.

So how can I apply `the_title` filter for just `post` and `page` titles, but not menu titles?

```
function pppp_title_update( $title, $id = null ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
       if(is_singular(array('post','page')) || is_archive() || is_home()){
            if(in_the_loop()){
                $current_post_id = get_the_ID();
                $new_titile = get_post_meta($current_post_id, 'pp_new_title',true);
                return $new_titile;  
            }                     
       } 
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'pppp_title_update', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Have you tried e.g.  `if( ! is_nav_menu_item( $id ) ){ ... }` within your filter callback to avoid filtering the title of nav menu items?

Comment: `if( ! is_nav_menu_item( $id ) )` check will exclude a custom nav menu item link, however, if the nav menu item itself is a page or post, it'll be filtered twice with `the_title` filter. In that case, this condition will work only once (i.e. not when `the_title` is fired for filtering the original post / page title within the menu).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Problem Description:

Let me rephrase the question first. You want to:

1. Set new title to all `post` and `page` type from a meta field.
2. You want this to happen everywhere (home page, single page, widgets etc.)
3. However, you don't want this title change to happen if the title is on the Navigation Menu.

### Solution:

Before I give you the CODE, let me explain a few points first (based on your CODE):

### How to change titles of all posts and pages:

You already know the use of `the_title` filter. However, if you want to target all `post` and `page` type titles (but not custom post types), then your condition:

```
is_singular(array('post','page')) || is_archive() || is_home()
```

will not work. For example, it'll change custom post type on an archive page or the home page as well. This condition doesn't check if the title we are filtering is a `page` or `post` type. Instead, it checks if the page itself is either singular (`post` or `page`) or it's an archive (category, tag etc.) page or the home page. So custom post types in these pages also gets affected. Additionally, if there is a widget in a custom post type (singular) page, then by this logic, `page` or `post` titles in that widget will not be affected there.

To fix that, we need a different check, like:

```
$post = get_post( $id );
if ( $post instanceof WP_Post && ( $post->post_type == 'post' || $post->post_type == 'page' ) )
```

### Why Navigation Menu title is also changed & how to stop it:

WordPress applies `the_title` filter twice on the navigation menu items' title (if the menu items correspond to existing posts or pages).

1. First as the corresponding post or page title. This happens in the `wp_setup_nav_menu_item()` function of `wp-includes/nav-menu.php` file.
2. Then as the Menu item title itself. This happens in the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class.

For your requirement, we need to stop the `the_title` filter both the times.

Fortunately, WordPress has two filters: `pre_wp_nav_menu` fires before filtering menu titles and `wp_nav_menu_items` fires after filtering menu titles. So we can use these two filters to first remove the `the_title` filter for nav menu item titles and then add the `the_title` filter back again for other titles.

### CODE

You may use the following CODE in the theme's `functions.php` file or as a separate plugin:

```
function wpse309151_title_update( $title, $id = null ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && ! is_null( $id ) ) {
        $post = get_post( $id );
        if ( $post instanceof WP_Post && ( $post->post_type == 'post' || $post->post_type == 'page' ) ) {
            $new_titile = get_post_meta( $id, 'pp_new_title', true );
            if( ! empty( $new_titile ) ) {
                return $new_titile;
            }
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse309151_title_update', 10, 2 );

function wpse309151_remove_title_filter_nav_menu( $nav_menu, $args ) {
    // we are working with menu, so remove the title filter
    remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse309151_title_update', 10, 2 );
    return $nav_menu;
}
// this filter fires just before the nav menu item creation process
add_filter( 'pre_wp_nav_menu', 'wpse309151_remove_title_filter_nav_menu', 10, 2 );

function wpse309151_add_title_filter_non_menu( $items, $args ) {
    // we are done working with menu, so add the title filter back
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse309151_title_update', 10, 2 );
    return $items;
}
// this filter fires after nav menu item creation is done
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpse309151_add_title_filter_non_menu', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer. Seems like this will be worked fine. Thanks again... But I am on a trip. I will check your answer on this Friday and let you know the result.

Comment: That's OK, take your time.

Comment: This is worked without any problem. Thanks for the answer and explanation :-)

Answer (score 6):

WordPress navigation editor has ability to change menu title regardless of the title of the post/page.

If you need more automated solution code below will replace title of the post/page everywhere using `the_title` filter but restore default title of the menu item using `nav_menu_item_title` filter.

```
/**
 * Replace post/page title on home, single and archive pages.
 *
 * @param string $title   Post title
 * @param int    $post_id Post ID
 *
 * @return string New post tilte
 */
function wpse_309151_get_replace_default_title_from_meta( $title, $post_id ) {

    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );

    if( !is_admin() && ( $post_type === 'post' || $post_type === 'page' ) ) {

        $new_title = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpse_309151_post_title', true);

        if( $new_title && !empty( $new_title ) ) {
            return $new_title;
        }
    }

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_309151_get_replace_default_title_from_meta', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Restore default post/page title in navigation
 *
 * @param string   $title The menu item's title.
 * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
 * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
 * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
 *
 * @return string Restored post title
 */
function wpse_309151_get_restore_default_title_for_navigation( $title, $item, $args, $depth ) {

    // Remove filter to not affect title
    remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_309151_get_replace_default_title_from_meta', 10, 2 );

    $post_id = $item->object_id;
    $title   = get_the_title( $post_id );

    // Add the title filter back
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_309151_get_replace_default_title_from_meta', 10, 2 );

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_title', 'wpse_309151_get_restore_default_title_for_navigation', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: This reverts Navigation Label to page title. Go and edit the menu, expand a page, change its label, save it. With this function the label is ignored and the page title shows instead. Normally the label is shown in the menu.

Comment: In the first sentence of this answer I stated that changing label is in my opinion better solution but I provided code for more automated solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the post object (get_the_ID(); or  $post->ID;  are essentially the same) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351038/get-the-current-page-id-inside-wordpress-plugin-page, then you should also be able to do use either https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/ to check the type or

```
if (in_array($post->post_type, array('post', 'page')) {
... swop the title
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the title only for a specific post, you can use the "the_title" filter like this:

```
function replace_page_title( $title, $id = null )   {

// Change the post title only if post ID is eg. 123
if ( $id == 123 ) {

    $title = "New Title";
}

return $title;
}

add_filter( 'the_title', 'replace_page_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This answer does not address the issue described in the question. This will also apply to the post tile in menus.