# add_filter( 'the_title' gets through this if statement twice

Tags: filters, title

I am using the accepted answer shown here: [Apply the_title() filter in post & page title, but not in menu title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309151/apply-the-title-filter-in-post-page-title-but-not-in-menu-title#answer-309356)

For some reason, the code is getting through this if statement twice:

```
if ( ! is_admin() && $post instanceof WP_Post && ( $post->post_type == 'page' ) && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {
```

I am already using the `pre_wp_nav_menu` and `wp_nav_menu_items` filters as shown on that answer.

What would be making this code run twice please?  Or how would I debug to find out what is calling it and letting it through the if twice?

Sorry, I would ask as a follow-up on the posted question, but I evidently can't comment yet.

**UPDATE**:  I used debug_traceback to determine what functions were calling this function twice. The answer:
`function the_title` in `post-template.php`  (line 43)
and
`function the_title_attribute` in `post-template.php` (line 89) (which is evidently used to sanitize the title)

Interestingly, when signed in on wordpress, only line 89 gets called and NOT line 43 so the `add_filter 'the_title'` function only gets called once if you are signed in.

So...Is it fine to leave `add_filter 'the_title'` as being called twice if you are not signed in...or why is it only called once if you ARE signed in?

Comment: is this the answer or is this the comment? Stack exchange isn't a discussion forum, an answer is a self contained solution to the question. If you want to add more information to your question, you should edit it or leave a comment instead

Comment: Noted, thanks.  I've updated the question.